# Unable to download excel file with https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have written an api in ASP.NET Core which downloads excel file. My code is -

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetReport")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(string itemKey = "", bool detailed = false, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        var stream = await _logic.PerpetualDiscrepencyReport(itemKey, detailed, ct);
        return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx");
    }
}
```

In Local I am able to hit url and download report with both http and https. But in Staging (IIS server) I am unable to hit the report url with https. If I use http I am able to download report by hitting the url. should I do anything in iis configuration to able to get report with https. Other apis are working fine with https.

Comment: Check the permission and who created the files.  It sound like a permission issue.  Compare the excel files with the ones that are working.

Comment: If it fails to perform something expected, check your logs for the exact exception message and details.

Comment: It's not file permission issue. I am able to download same file on http but not on https.

Comment: @jegtugado I am not getting anything in logs. Interesting thing is when I make api call with javascript on any url(https or https) it works fine. But on hitting url directly in browser only http works.

Comment: what response do you get from the server (or browser) when you are using HTTPS? Have you checked the browser's Network log to see what happens? Have you tried an alternative tool such as PostMan to see what response is received? There's some basic debugging info missing from your question.

Comment: @ADyson I tried with postman, I am getting 200 result. I am able to download file with Javascript. But with https it says page not found

Comment: So hitting the HTTPS staging URL with PostMan gets you a 200 response, but hitting the same URL through the browser gets you an error? Does the PostMan response actually contain the file data (as well as being a 200 response)? Does the call to it through the browser return a 200 response, or something else? (Use your browser's Developer Tools to monitor it via the Network tab, or use something like Fiddler to intercept the request.) We need to play spot-the-difference between the two requests and responses.